# Extract text of element line by line

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am using BeautifulSoup to extract various elements from a website.  I have run across a situation for which I am unable to determine an answer.  I want to extract the text of a link, but the link is line broken over 3 lines.  For example:

```
<span class="location-address">
<a href="https://www.google.com/maps" target="_blank">
"123 Main St"
<br>
"Suite 456" 
<br> 
"Everywhere, USA 12345"
</a>
```

When I use `find_all("span",{"class":"location-address"})[0].text` I am given something like "123 Main StSuite 456Everywhere, USA 12345" and I would prefer a more natural response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try to get `find_all("span",{"class":"location-address")[0].contents` instead of `find_all("span",{"class":"location-address")[0].text`. It should return all html content within link tag. Then you may replace `<br />` with `\n` or do whatever you need.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not successful in implementing your suggestion.  I have edited my original post to reflect an example more representative of the data I am attempting to collect.  I have added the quotation marks surrounding the text on each line of the address.  I'm not sure if that is causing the issue.  I have, however, successfully replaced text that appears in one of the address lines (i.e. "Everywhere") with other text using your suggested `.replace('Everywhere','newtext')` method.

Comment: Sorry, I missed a part about a link. To get all text within a link you should select `span`, then `a` within it, and then its content. So the code would be like this: `soup.find_all("span", "location-address")[0].find_all("a")[0].contents` It will gave non-formated content of the `a` tag.

Answer (score 0):

If you only have one `span` tag with `class=location-address` then simply use the [`find()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find) method.

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> html = """<span class="location-address">
... <a href="https://www.google.com/maps" target="_blank">
... "123 Main St"
... <br>
... "Suite 456" 
... <br> 
... "Everywhere, USA 12345"
... </a>"""
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
>>> soup.find('span', class_='location-address').find_next('a').get_text(strip=True).replace('"', '')
'123 Main StSuite 456Everywhere, USA 12345'
```

But if you have more than one "span" tag with the given class, using the [`find_all()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#calling-a-tag-is-like-calling-find-all) method you can do something like this:

```
>>> for span in soup.find_all('span', class_='location-address'):
...     span.find('a').get_text(strip=True).replace('"', '')
... 
'123 Main StSuite 456Everywhere, USA 12345'
```

Or use a [css selector](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors):

```
>>> for a in soup.select('span.location-address > a'):
...     a.get_text(strip=True).replace('"', '')
... 
'123 Main StSuite 456Everywhere, USA 12345'
```